# Open folder dialog in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Does anybody knows how to have an open folder dialog in Silverlight?
Any third party controls?

I know there is a OpenFileDialog but this is not what I'm looking for. I want a dialog for folders only.

Thanks.

Comment: means.... select only folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SilverLight 4 does not provide an OpenFolderDialog control so you may have to create your own. For more info check the following link:
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Folder-Dialog-in-Silverlight-4.aspx

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN.

> Silverlight does not have a browse
>   folder dialog box and you cannot use
>   the OpenFileDialog to just select a
>   folder.

Comment: thanks shoban, I've read that also but is there a work around for this? are there any third party controls I could use?

Comment: Like mcxiand said. Create your own user control :)

Comment: ya maybe that's the only way out of this. :)

Answer (score 1):

A folder browser dialog would serve no purpose.

SL3 it is by deliberate design that the SL can only access a file (not a folder) and only if that file it is specifically selected by the user in the OpenFileDialog.  Its not even possible to determine the folder in which the file is found.

Comment: This was true until Silverlight 5. MSDN: 'In Silverlight 5, trusted applications (...) can do the following: Access the local file system without restrictions.'

Comment: More docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721082%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own user control for this as this is not supported currently by Silverlight.

Comment: thanks. maybe this is the only way out. unless someone could give me some light. :)

Comment: You won't be able to create your own, because Silverlight (intentionally) does not give the developer access to a user's hard-drive (to do so would be a major security issue).

Comment: I see thanks for the info. Do you have any idea on this? Why does silverlight have a file open dialog and don't have a folder open dialog if security issue is concern? hmm.. I'll dig some more...

Comment: This wasn't possible until SL5 with full trust.